# Specializing a Hydra configuration with Explicit Nesting

Tags: fb-hydra

I would like to have:

```sh
conf/
├── config.yaml
├── data
│   └── data.yaml
├── render
│   └── renderer.yaml
├── storage
│   └── local.yaml
└── text
    ├── font.yaml
    └── regions.yaml
```

Where, in the `config.yaml`, the `text/font.yaml` assigned to `font` and `text/regions.yaml` to `regions`, something like:

```yaml
defaults:
  - font: text.font
  - regions: text.regions
  - render: renderer
  - data: data
  - storage: local
```

or

```yaml
defaults:
  - font:
    - text/font
  - regions:
    - text/regions
  - render: renderer
  - data: data
  - storage: local
```

The above do not work!

Would it be possible to achieve the desired result at the `yaml` level somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called changing the *package* of your constructed config, see:

- https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages#default-list-package-keywords
- https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/terminology

In your case your `font` and `regions` are located under the *group* `text`, but you want to move it to the respective *packages*  `font` and `regions`.
You can move any config option to any package namespace you want by specifying `<group>@<package>`, i.e.:

```yaml
defaults:
  - text@font: font
  - text@regions: regions
  - render: renderer
  - data: data
  - storage: local
```